# ostringstream operator[] giving compile error when trying to read buffer

Tags: c++, compilation, buffer, ostringstream

I have a class that extends ostringstream class.

```
Class A: public ostringstream
{

}
```

I want to read data of specified size and a specific offset from that object. So trying:

```
A a_;
a_ << data1 << data2;
string datax(a_[offset], size);
```

But getting a compile error at string datax statement.

```
error: no match for operator[] in ...
```

How can I copy data from object a_ for a specified offset and size? I dont want to remove data from the object a_.

**NOTE**: The class was designed by someone else and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe with the code you have you could do:

```
a_ << data1 << data2;
string datax(&a_.str()[offset], size);
```

which looks a bit ugly to me. Why not just use plain `std::stringstream` instead? (unless you have a strong reason to inherit from `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Class A that has been cleardy designed by someone else, which I cant change. So I am having to do this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, nothing in the standard guarantees you that deriving from `std::ostringstream` will work. You'd be better not doing it at all.

Second, there is no `operator []` for `std::ostringstream` so why should there be one for `A`?

Finally, you can call `str()` on `a_` and get an `std::string` with the contents of the buffer. I'm not sure if that would help you, what you want to do is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call to str() method:

```
ostringstream oss (ostringstream::out);
oss << "abcdef";
string s = oss.str();
cout << s.substr(1, 3) << endl;
```

This example would output "bcd".